# How can I sort a column in a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to sort a DataGrid column in Visual Studio 2008 (C#). I've followed all the examples and searches, but its not working.

Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using ShopFloor.Components;

namespace ShopFloor
{

     public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{       
     protected dsSF dsSF1;
     protected System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter daDtl;
     protected System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter daHdrUpTo;
     protected System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter daUpTo;


       private DataView dv;

  private dsSF DataSetSF
  {
    get
    {
        return (dsSF) Session["DataSetSF"];
    }
    set
    {
        Session["DataSetSF"] = value;
    }
  }


    protected string SortColumn
    {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["SortColumn"];
            if (o != null)
            {
                if ((string)o == "Item_Number")
                {
                      ViewState["SortColumn"] = "Item_Number";
                      return "Item_Number";
                }

                return (string)o;
            }
            else
               return "Item_Number";
        }
        set
        {
             ViewState["SortColumn"] = value;
        }
    }



     protected bool SortAscend
       {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["SortAscend"];
            if (o != null)
                return (bool)o;
            else
               return true;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["SortAscend"] = value;
        }
     }


//==============================================================================

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
    ShowHideTOC();
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {           
        daHdrUpTo.SelectCommand.Parameters["@WC_Id"].Value = WorkCellId;
                 daHdrUpTo.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Required_Date"].Value = upDate;
        daHdrUpTo.Fill(dsSF1, "SFD10011");
        DataSetSF = dsSF1;
        dgSF.DataBind();

              DataTable dt = DataSetSF.Tables[“SFD10011”];
              dv = dt.DefaultView;
              Session["grid"] = dv;

    }
    else
    {
        dsSF1 = DataSetSF;
    }
       }


   protected void dgSF_SortCommand(object source,  
         System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
   {
       SortDataGrid(e.SortExpression);
        }              

   private void SortDataGrid(string sort)
     {
        string currentSortColumn = SortColumn;
        SortColumn = sort;

        if (currentSortColumn == SortColumn)
            SortAscend = !SortAscend;
        else
            SortAscend = true;

  BindDataGrid();
     }



     private void BindDataGrid()
     {
        object o = Session["grid"];
        if (o != null)
        {
       dv = (DataView)Session["grid"];

         if (SortAscend)
               dv.Sort = SortColumn + " " + "ASC";         // ASCENDING ORDER
             else
                 dv.Sort = SortColumn + " " + "DESC";        // DESCENDING ORDER

             Session["grid"] = dv;

             dgSF.DataSource = dv;               
        }
        else
             dgSF.DataSource = null;             

        dgSF.DataBind();                        
       }


    }
}
```

I set my column headers as templates and added the fields in the "Sort Expression" and i set my DataGrid to allow sorting.

Can't figure out why its not sorting. Any help would be appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Your sorting code works fine! It should be something else. Can you update your question with the markup?

Comment: @afzalulh What do you mean? Its not working for me. What do you mean by update with a markup?